# Best practices for using components with a Blazor WebAssembly app if it is ASPNET Core Hosted?

Tags: .net-core, components, blazor, client-server, razor-components

I have a functioning Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) component which is ASP.NET Core Hosted and contains three projects: client, server, and shared.  The client-side component connects to a SQL Server database using Web API endpoints contained in a controller file within the server-side app.

I would now like to share this component with multiple apps. Would the best practice be to use a Razor Class Library (RCL) or to just keep the component in project format and directly add/reference it within projects that will use it? If an RCL is recommended, how do I handle the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer to my question. It appears that prior to .NET 6 it was possible to share Blazor components by sharing their projects. However, with .NET 6 this now generates an error and Razor Class Library's (RCLs) are the recommended method for sharing WebAssembly components.  Source: [GitHub aspnetcore issue #36732](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36732)

I also posted to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/740747/how-to-use-a-razor-class-library-rcl-with-a-hybrid.html) and to date have been unable to find a way to combine client-side WASM classes and server-side controller classes into a single RCL. From what I have learned so far, I can see two options:

1. Use an RCL for the client-side component and a regular class library (or second RCL) for the server-side controller. (I have not tested this).
2. Convert to a server-side Blazor project. This is the solution I ended up using. It does not require a Web API/controller and sharing components via RCL works well. Bonus, coding/debugging is easier and the project loads faster. This solution is working well for my present needs.